# Delphi Windows service name conflict with project name

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I have a basic file with the name DataCapture.dpr with

```
program DataCapture;
```

inside.

Then I had to give the an other name to the service itself to avoid name conflict:

```
TDataCaptureService = class(TService)
```

Now when I register it, the service gets registered under "DataCaptureService" registry key, but I want:

1. To register it under "DataCapture" registry key
2. To keep DataCapture.exe file name
3. To keep DataCapture.dpr file name

How to achieve this?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't care what registry key it goes under. That's for Windows only. I suspect you have hard-coded this registry key inside your application, which is why you don't want it to change.

Comment: Try changing the name of your service to 'DataCapture' not at designtime - I think the IDE would complain about the naming conflict with the project name - but at runtime, in the `OnCreate` event handler: `Name := 'DataCapture';`

Comment: I'v tried to change name in constructor. It hadn't any effect.

Comment: What you set in the constructor might be overwritten later when the service component is initialized from the dfm stream. `OnCreate` might be a better place to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The naming conflict prevention is only imposed by the IDE at designtime. To avoid it you can simply set your service name at runtime, e.g. in the `OnCreate` event:

```
Name := 'DataCapture';
```

or, best of all, override `DoCreate` method, because `OnCreate` is meant for external things:

```
procedure TDataCaptureService.DoCreate();
begin
  Name := 'DataCapture';
  inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve all three of your desires - you have to sacrifice something. In this case, change your project's name to something else, and then post-build, change the EXE name to what you want. The Delphi compiler simply will not allow the same identifier to be used twice.

---

There is an alternative too. By default, services compiled from Delphi have their own `/install` `/uninstall` parameters you can call, which internally uses your `Name` for the service. But, you could ignore that and install it externally via WinAPI using whatever name you want (thus generating a corresponding registry key for your new name).

Comment: Thank you Jerry, but registry key name influences how I start it with `net start` from command line.

Comment: @Paul No it doesn't - it's the service's "name" which matters when you start/stop. Windows just happens to use the service's name as the registry key when the service is installed. The only time you should care about this registry key is if you choose to write a `Description` of the service upon installation. Nothing else.

Comment: Even then, you shouldn't be writing the description to the Registry directly anyway, you should be using `ChangeServiceConfig2()` instead with the `dwInfoLevel` set to `SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION`